# Intuition behind errors

Tags: physical-chemistry

I want to ask a question about the multiplication of two variables and the error associated with the process.

I was learning about calculating errors in the physical labs at school and was taught that the following formula was used to calculate errors:

> $\frac{\triangle Z}{Z} = \frac{\triangle A}{A} + \frac{\triangle B}{B}$

This made sense, given that we are in essence calculating percentage uncertainties and these are added when calculating the uncertainty of Z.

However, in my current undergraduate lab, we square each term:

> $(\frac{\triangle Z}{Z})^2 = (\frac{\triangle A}{A})^2 + (\frac{\triangle B}{B})^2$

and I cannot find any reference to explain the purpose of squaring the values.

Why do we square each term as above?

Comment: Do you assume that the uncertainties of $A$ and $B$ are correlated or independent?

Comment: It is complicated. See the [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Example_formulae) in the Wikipedia article on "Propagation of uncertainty."

Comment: We are told the measurements of A and B are independent.

Comment: In principle, the second formula with the squares is better, according to the Gaussian theory of error propagation. But in the lower classes, we accept the formula with the non-squared errors. Anyway the difference between the two calculations is not severe. And the beginning student hate both squares, and then extracting square roots. This is also true for students at higher levels...

Comment: @vik1245  Possibly you stumble over «variance».  For the later, if you have a function $z$ which is the result of two mutually independent functions $a$ and $b$, you access the variance of $z$ _via_ the partial derivatives: $\mathrm{var}(z) = (\frac{\partial{}z}{\partial{}a})^2 \cdot \mathrm{var}(a) + (\frac{\partial{}z}{\partial{}b})^2 \cdot \mathrm{var}(b)$. Using the squares here ensures that the variances will add, regardless of the sign of either summand, hence for either $z = a + b$, or $z = a - b$.  So the second equation comes closer to the principle of determining the variance.

Comment: @vik1245 ... as the $\Delta{}b$, for example, _could_ be negative, hence rendering the fraction $\frac{\Delta{}b}{b}$ negative -- just depending on the order of minuend and subtrahend.  _This_ could lead to the (erroneous) result that the error in $z$ _decreases_.

Comment: @Buttonwood nailed it! Never use the first expression, period. For lots of relevant information, including worked examples, download this (free) on the web: EURACHEM/CITAC Guide, “Quantifying Uncertainty in Analytical Measurement”, 3rd Ed., 2012. It is often just referred to as QUAM.

Comment: @EdV With my accidental find of the «Breakthroughs in Statistics» (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0919-5,  https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4380-9, https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0667-5; especially volume 2) and now your suggestion _on top_, the initial anticipation of a reading weekend is at least exchanged by a study weekend ahead.  Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @Buttonwood Thanks for links to those amazing books!

Comment: @EdV Again an unexpected find indeed (at least, for a chemist).  An additional example of potentially missed knowledge for each Joe who thinks «just email the library to xerox me pages x--z of the book indicated by google and Scifinder» (helas, just missing to peek into the ones in the same shelf).